# Android Studio: No Such Method Error: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an app which uses google maps API. It all worked until I upgraded android studio. Now whenever I click on the button to go on maps activity, the app crashes giving this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.prin.gaurav.app-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes20.dex)
```

I searched on the web to know it is a bug and tried getting rid of it using my limited knowledge, but I am getting nowhere at this point.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/744

Comment: I had a look on that, but it didn't solve my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below line in build.gradle;

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

like this:

```
defaultConfig 
{
applicationId "yourProjectPackage"
minSdkVersion 15
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
targetSdkVersion 23

multiDexEnabled true //important
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Can you elaborate what does this line  do and what was my actual problem?

Comment: You can refer this link for more information....https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html        Kindly upvote and mark my answer as helpful.